# how to perform multiple constraints wald-test in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am new to R, and want to use it to perform a series of wald test.
I have a model like this:

```
model1 <- lm(score~A+B+C+D,data = as2)
```

which packge or command can help me test the null hypothesis: `10B = 3C`?
I only know how to use `wald.test` to test if `A=B=0`

thank you for your help.

I try to use `wald.test` in the `clubSandwich` package, however I can only use it to test if `B=C=0`

```
wald.test(Sigma = vcov(model1), b = coef(model1), Terms = 2:3)
```

How can I use the same command to test if `10B=3C` or `10B-3C=O`?